# Improving Point Cloud Slice Parameter's Adjusting loop

Tags: c#

This part of the function is adjusting the sliceDepthSubtractor and startDepthSlice parameters that are used in order to take a geometrical slice (h) of a point cloud object (a[i]), that it will be used for determining if the object is a circle or not.

If the slice it is containing too few points in order to make a circle determination, the slice is retaken with different parameters before throwing an exception.

sliceDepthSubtractor and startDepthSlice are local parameters that are filled with data from XML file parsing class (The XML file is read at the application initialization inside of a dedicated class). Initial values are 1 (sliceDepthSubtractor) and 0.98 (startDepthSlice).

The list of point cloud object (a) is given as a parameter to this method.

As I hate nested loops, I would like to improve this code.

```
double sliceDepthSubtractor =  xlmClass.sliceDepthSubtractor; 
double startDepthSlice      =  xlmClass.startDepthSlice;
bool adjustSliceDepthSubtractor = true;
while (adjustSliceDepthSubtractor)
{
   adjustSliceDepthSubtractor = false;
   bool adjustingStartDepthSlice = true;
   while (adjustingStartDepthSlice)
   {
     adjustingStartDepthSlice = false;
     for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) 
     {     
        PointCloud h = TakeSlice(a[i],sliceDepthSubtractor, 
                     startDepthSlice);

       if ((h.PointCount < 100) && (startDepthSlice > 0.10))
       {
         startDepthSlice  -= 0.1;
         adjustingStartDepthSlice  = true;
         break;    
       } 
       if ((h.PointCount < 100) && (sliceDepthSubtractor < 3)) 
       { 
         sliceDepthSubtractor += 1;
         adjustSliceDepthSubtractor = true;
         break;    
       } 
       if (h.PointCount < 100)
       {
         throw new ComputationException("Insufficient Points");
       }
       LmsSolver(h, a[i]);
     }      
   }
   if (adjustSliceDepthSubtractor) {continue;}
   Save(a);
}
```

Comment: Not enough information here. Using a method name `doSomething()` looks like example code. If you don't want to share the method here, at least post the original code (with the real methodname)  and explain wether the method has any side effects like changing `a[i]` etc. In addition, please state in your question what `a[]` is. Last but not least please state in the title of your question what the code is doing because everybody who ask a question here want to have cleaner and/or faster code.

Comment: `a`, `sliceDepthSubtractor` and `startDepthSliceParameter` - fields of the class?

Comment: I understand and I will do my best to better describe the sample.

Comment: @Vladds7 what do you check by `a[i].Count < 10`? and what are those magic numbers 3 and 10? `startDepthSlice ` and `startDepthSliceParameter` - different variables or misprint?

Comment: Thank you for this comments. They made me realise how much I need to improve my explaining skills.  As the source code, I do not have the access to the external methods. My work is related to parameters adjustments, and I would like to learn as much as possible from here.

Comment: I hope that I managed to make the code mode clear. Unfortunately I do not have access to takeSlice and lmsSolver methods.

Comment: @Vladds7 one more question - what is the output of this loop - parameters or modified `a` list which you are saving? I.e. do you need parameters at all after loop

Comment: @Sergey: The output of this loop is the a list. The whole idea of these loops is to avoid the exception throw by re-slicing with adjusted parameters.

Comment: @Vladds7 i.e. `a` is modified in the `lmsSolver` and/or `takeSlice` methods?

Comment: Does adjusting a parameter always result in larger point clouds? Also, are you sure you want to call `lmsSolver` on point clouds before you've established proper parameter values (possibly causing a lot of useless work to be done)?

Comment: @Pieter: parameters are used only to take a slice containing sufficient points in order to call solver.

Comment: @Sergery: a[i] is modified only by Solver.

Comment: @Vladds7: I understand that, but what I'm trying to say is: do your parameter adjustments always cause `takeSlice` to return a point cloud with more points, or is it possible that a parameter adjustment causes smaller point clouds to be returned?

Comment: They can return smaller points, and therefore trigger the exception throw.  Also I start the startDepthSlice  with maximum admissible value and decrese by 0.1 and I  increase the sliceDepthSubtractor to maxium value (2). This gives like 2(substractor 1, 2)  * 8 (slice from 0.98 to 0.18) adjustments.

Comment: When I look at your last edit I'm starting to think that this code isn't real and was/is pseudocode.

Comment: Function names are pseudo.  That is why I renamed them as Peter mentioned in his answer.   In reality they belong to another classes and have a quiet stuffy irelevant initialization that I can not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same pattern in both your loops - enable some flag before the loop, and disable that flag immediately as you enter the loop. So basically you want to always enter the loop and always exit loop unless something will enable the flag.

```
bool flag = true;
while (flag)
{
    flag = false;
    // ...
    // some condition can set flag to true

    if (flag)
      continue;
}
```

Same can be achieved without using a flag - use infinite loop and break it only when your exit condition happen

```
while (true)
{
    // ...
    if (sliceDepthSubstractorAdjusted)
       break;        
}
```

Now, what about nested loop? I stick to single indentation level rule of thumb. To avoid arrow anti-pattern. You can move loop logic to separate method and return outer exit loop condition from that method. Thus you can keep loop even without a body:

```
while (!TryAdjustSliceDepthSubstructor()) {}
```

Pretty descriptive - repeat adjustment until it done. But you should pass different values to that method - `a`, `sliceDepthSubtractor`, `startDepthSlice`. And this code will not look so good with all these parameters flying around. The reason is that we keep data and logic separated. So simply put logic (points adjustment with some parameters) and data (parameters) into the class.

```
public class Butcher// Of course, you should change the name
{
     private double sliceDepthSubtractor;
     private double startDepthSlice;

     public Butcher(double sliceDepthSubtractor, double startDepthSlice)
     {
         // initialize fields here
     }

     public void AdjustForSlicing(List<PointCloud> points) { ... }

     // TakeSlice
     // lmsSolver
}
```

Now you can initialize this class and your code with outer loop will look like

```
var points // List<PointCloud>
var butcher = new Butcher(xlm.sliceDepthSubtractor, xlm.startDepthSlice);
butcher.AdjustForSlicing(points);
Save(points); // use PascalCase names for methods
```

---

Looks clean. Let's look inside

```
public void AdjustForSlicing(List<PointCloud> points)
{
    while(!AllSlicesContainEnoughPoints(points)) // surprise - single loop here
    {
        if (CanAdjustStartDepthSlice)
        {
            startDepthSlice -= 0.1;
            continue;
        }

        if (CanAdjustDepthSubstractor)
        {
            // NOTE: Consider to reset startDepthSlice here
            sliceDepthSubtractor += 1;
            continue;
        }

        throw new ComputationException("Insufficient Points");        
    }
}

private bool AllSlicesContainEnoughPoints(List<PointCloud> points)
{
    const int minCountOfPointsInSlice = 100;

    foreach(var point in points)
    {
        var slice = TakeSlice(point, sliceDepthSubtractor, startDepthSlice);

        if (slice.PointCount < minCountOfPointsInSlice)
            return false;

        lmsSolver(slice, point);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And a couple of helper methods. Consider replacing magic numbers with constants

```
private bool CanAdjustStartDepthSlice => startDepthSlice > 0.1;
private bool CanAdjustDepthSubstractor => sliceDepthSubtractor < 3;
```

Now you can read this code as a specification.

***Note:*** Probably we should not modify initial values of `startDepthSlice` and  `sliceDepthSubtractor` when we are adjusting points in order to be able to call butcher serveral times. But I'll leave this exercise for you :)

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer!  This is how I should do it. But since I have to keep a small footprint on this project, I will not create the Butcher. Indeed I will move this adjustment to an existing UtilityMethod.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help you refactor your code because it's incomplete and lacks any context so I can only give you a general advice about

> I hate nested loops, I would like to improve this code.

In order to get rid of them you should start improving your code by moving parts of it into other smaller methods so that some of the nested loops will *vanish* because probably you would take them to somewhere else.

> This part of the function [..]

If what you have posted is really only a part of something bigger then there is a much larger problem then this three nested loops and you should address this issue first.

Answer (score 2):

**Overview**

You need to process multiple point clouds, which must match some criteria (they all must have at least 100 points). If any cloud is too small, you adjust one of two parameters (up to some limits) and try again.

If, after several adjustments, some clouds are still too small, the code gives up and throws an exception. Otherwise, if all clouds are big enough, they're run through a solver method and the results are saved (I assume that's what `save()` does).

**Improvements**

Each parameter has its own boolean flag and while loop, but you don't need that much detail: the code inside that for loop already checks which parameter can still be modified. So you can replace those while loops with a single 'repeat this until all clouds are large enough' loop instead.

However, each time you encounter a cloud that's too small you adjust a parameter and start all over again. Because you're also calling a solver method as soon as a cloud is large enough, that means you may repeatedly be doing useless work. It probably makes sense to split this method into two parts: one that determines proper parameter values, and one that actually solves the final clouds. And if those parameter adjustment never result in smaller clouds, the parameter-value-determining part doesn't need to start all over either: it can simply adjust a parameter and try again for the current value of `i`.

Finally, try using more descriptive names than `h`, `a` and `xml`. You'll be happy you did when you have to revisit this code a couple months later. Oh, and method names should start with capital letters, according to C# naming conventions. Consistency improves code readability, which makes maintaining it easier.